# C++ send data to parallel port in WinXP

Tags: c++, parallel-port

I want to send mark to parallel port using C++ in winXP system. I checked the information and wrote the following code:

```
HANDLE parallelPort = CreateFile(L"LPT1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if(parallelPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout << "handle error" << std::endl;

int *data = new int[1];
data[0] = 4;
WriteFile(parallelPort, data, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);


std::cout << "send success!" << std::endl;

CloseHandle(parallelPort);
```

I run this code, find `parallelPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` . But it doesn't print `send success!`. What's wrong with this code？
If you have used the software named "E-prime", I want to do the same as it:

```
WritePort &H378, 0
```

Comment: Oh, you want direct port I/O. There are libraries for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864431/does-inpout32-dll-inpoutx64-dll-handle-i-o-to-from-all-parallel-ports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to I/O ports in Windows XP? (Delphi7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167579/how-to-write-to-i-o-ports-in-windows-xp-delphi7)